# ld: library not found for -lGoogleAnalytics

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-analytics

I'm trying to use Google Analytics library with my xcode project. 
Everything was working for a few months but then I moved the files on my computer to different locations and now I'm getting this error. 
I tried fixing the Library Search Paths but I had no success.

Comment: try, copy the google analytics library into your project folder then add it newly...

Comment: I too have same doubt. Can anybody resolve this ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Pods to include the GoogleAnalytics iOS SDK into your project, it's worth noting that since the 3.0 release your 'other link flags' needs to include **-lGoogleAnalyticsServices** not the old **-lGoogleAnalytics**

Answer (score 0):

Removing 'Derived Data' for the project on Organizer helped me.

Comment: Not woking for me :-(

Answer (score 0):

Put "$(inherited)" in Library Search Paths for your target

Answer (score -1):

If you are using pods, check if the value of Library Search Path equals to "Multiple values"

if so, remove "Any Architecture | Any SDK" from both "Debug and Release" by clicking on the minus button beside it.

[image: detailed screenshot]